# C++ Incompatible iterators types

Tags: c++, iterator

I tried to print a graph and the compiler thew an error.

The error goes like this:
class "__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator, std::allocator>> *, std::vector, std::allocator>>, std::allocator, std::allocator>>>>>" has no member "begin"

The same happens with an end().

Here is the code:

```
void printGraph(std::vector<std::list<std::pair<int, int>>> graph)
{
    for (std::vector<std::list<std::pair<int, int>>>::iterator i = graph.begin(); i < graph.end(); i++)
    {
        for (std::list<std::pair<int, int>>::iterator j = i.begin(); j < i.end(); j++)
            printf("%d", (*j).first);
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

Comment: Note by the way, as your input variable is not a reference,  the whole vector of lists of pairs is copied locally to the function!!! Quite inefficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in you inner loop `i` is an iterator type. So `i` has to be dereferenced to reference to an object.

```
for (std::list<std::pair<int, int>>::iterator j = (*i).begin(); j != (*i).end(); j++)
```

However, you can also use the `->` operator to get access to the object's members

```
for (std::list<std::pair<int, int>>::iterator j = i->begin(); j != i->end(); j++)
```

Then you can use the `auto` keyword to save on specification of the iterator.

```
void printGraph(std::vector<std::list<std::pair<int, int>>> const& graph) {
    for (auto i = graph.begin(); i < graph.end(); i++)
    {
        for (auto j = i->begin(); j != i->end(); j++)
            printf("%d", j->first);
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

And even more compact, you can use a range-based for loop (C++11) and expand the pair through structured binding declaration (C++17)

```
void printGraph(std::vector<std::list<std::pair<int, int>>> const& graph) {
    for (auto const& lst : graph) {
        for (auto const& [first, second] : lst) {
            printf("%d", first);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

Secondly, a `std::list` has a [*LegacyBidirectionalIterator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator), which doesn't have an `operator <()` defined. Thus you cannot use `j < i.end()`. `j != i.end()` does work however.

edit: well then let's add another option... with the coming C++20 you will be able to use ranges, so the loops can look like this:

```
void printGraph(std::vector<std::list<std::pair<int, int>>> const& graph) {
    std::ranges::for_each (graph, [](auto const& lst) {
        std::ranges::for_each (lst, [](auto const& pr) {
            printf("%d", pr.first);
        });
        putchar('\n');
    });
}
```

Comment: In both cases, I cannot compare i and j.

Comment: The range-based `for` loop was introduced in C++11, not C++17. And the inner loop can still access the pairs in C++11, you just can't use the `[first, second]` syntax for that: `for (auto const& p : lst) { printf("%d", p.first); }`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I never said the range-based for loop is C++17. I only noted that expanding the pair is C++17. I dont think its really relevant, but I'll add that...